# Save Selected Text Range for Use Later Not working

Tags: javascript, range, contenteditable, execcommand

I am using `contenteditable` and highlighting some text. I want to then backup that text range, and at a later time give that range(text) a different color. If I check in my `zss_editor.restorerange` method I do get back a valid `selection` object, so it must be something incorrect in how I am previously saving that range.

```
var zss_editor = {};

// The current selection
zss_editor.currentSelection;

zss_editor.backuprange = function(){
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    zss_editor.currentSelection = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    zss_editor.currentSelection.setEnd(zss_editor.currentSelection.startContainer, zss_editor.currentSelection.startOffset);
}

zss_editor.restorerange = function(){
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(zss_editor.currentSelection);
    console.log(zss_editor.currentSelection);
}

zss_editor.setTextColor = function(color) {
    zss_editor.restorerange();
    document.execCommand("styleWithCSS", null, true);
    document.execCommand('foreColor', false, color);
    document.execCommand("styleWithCSS", null, false);
}

zss_editor.setBackgroundColor = function(color) {
    zss_editor.restorerange();
    document.execCommand("styleWithCSS", null, true);
    document.execCommand('hiliteColor', false, color);
    document.execCommand("styleWithCSS", null, false);
}
```

Working example on JS Fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/zedsaid/gC3jq/11/**

**Why, when I backup the range and want to restore it at a latter time, does it not work? Do I need to backup the range in a different way?**

Comment: Your'e not creating a "back-up" of the range, you'd need [`cloneRange()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range.cloneRange) to copy a range.

Comment: @Teemu Can you post an example?

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/d7UMt/)... Though there's something odd when changing the background, it changes after blurring and refocusing the window.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can backup the range by storing the startContainer & startOffset as well as the endContainer & endOffset.  To restore, you just create a new range object and set the start and end of that range object then add it to the selection

```
var zss_editor = {};

// The current selection
zss_editor.currentSelection;

zss_editor.backuprange = function(){
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    zss_editor.currentSelection = {"startContainer": range.startContainer, "startOffset":range.startOffset,"endContainer":range.endContainer, "endOffset":range.endOffset};

}

zss_editor.restorerange = function(){
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart(zss_editor.currentSelection.startContainer, zss_editor.currentSelection.startOffset);
    range.setEnd(zss_editor.currentSelection.endContainer, zss_editor.currentSelection.endOffset);
    selection.addRange(range);
    console.log(range);
}

zss_editor.setTextColor = function(color) {
    zss_editor.restorerange();
    document.execCommand("styleWithCSS", null, true);
    document.execCommand('foreColor', false, color);
    document.execCommand("styleWithCSS", null, false);
}

zss_editor.setBackgroundColor = function(color) {
    zss_editor.restorerange();
    document.execCommand("styleWithCSS", null, true);
    document.execCommand('hiliteColor', false, color);
    document.execCommand("styleWithCSS", null, false);
}

$('#backup').click(function() {
    zss_editor.backuprange();
});

$('#color1').click(function() {
    zss_editor.setTextColor('#007AFF');
});

$('#color2').click(function() {
    zss_editor.setBackgroundColor('#007AFF');
});
```

Comment: That gives me the error: `TypeError: '[object RangeConstructor]' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new Range()')`

Comment: What browser are you using? I didn't receive an error when testing it in JSFiddle

Comment: Using Safari for testing.

Comment: I've made a change to the code to use document.createRange() instead of using new Range(). That should hopefully resolve the issue.

Comment: Would it be easy to bring focus back to that range? E.g. highlight it again?

Comment: the selection.addRange() call should have re-highlighted the range for you.  As I don't have access to a safari browser I'm not sure if the calls to the execCommand() may have cause the range to not be highlighted. what you can do is call restorerange() again after executing all your execCommand() calls and see if that does the trick

Comment: No, it doesn't work in Firefox or Safari. It gives it color like I want, but I would love to give that range focus again and have it selected.

Comment: Hi T.V. Storing JSON.stringify(zss_editor.currentSelection.startContainer) in the chrome storage gives "{ }" empty string object. Same is with endContainer. How can we store the object?  Could you please help me out?